# How to safely close a pika BlockingConnection subscriber?

Tags: multithreading, amqp, pika

According to the docs [Pika is not thread safe](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html):

> Pika does not have any notion of threading in the code. If you want to use Pika with threading, make sure you have a Pika connection per thread, created in that thread. It is not safe to share one Pika connection across threads, with one exception: you may call the connection method add_callback_threadsafe from another thread to schedule a callback within an active pika connection.

Lets say I have a subscriber which I have started using [`channel.start_consuming()`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-python.html).  That thread will be blocked waiting for messages to arrive.  These messages might be a long time apart (hours sometimes).

Surely if I want to safely / cleanly shutdown the subscriber, I must do-so from another thread?  Or else how can I trigger the consumer to break out of blocking?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `connection.process_data_events()` instead of just `channel.start_consuming()`. The advantage here is that you could do something like this to close a connection.

```
def consume_messages(self):
    while self.running:
        self.connection.process_data_events()
        sleep(0.1)
    self.connection.close()
```

You would then just close the connection by setting `self.running` to `False`.